# How to enable exception.log and system.log in Magento database?

Tags: magento, exception, logging

In Magento how do I enable `exception.log` and `system.log` at the database level?

I know I can do it through admin backend (**which I do not want to do**).

What value needs to be changed? I assumed that `dev/log/active` needed to be set to `1` in `core_config_data`, but I did this and that did not enable logging.
Thanks!

Comment: make sure you have write permission (777) for directory `var/log/`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your solution is right. That's the right place to enable it in the DB. If it's not working for you, try clearing the cache. If still not working, try `select * from core_config_data where path = "dev/log/active";` and check if it is not disabled for a particular scope that's overriding your setting

Comment: And if it's still not working, check that the user running the shell script has write permission to var/log.

Answer (score 3):

Use following query

```
INSERT INTO `yourmagentodbname`.`core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ( 'default', '0', 'dev/log/active', '1');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check folder permissions.
You need to give permissions for the user that is running apache.

In my case just the sub directory "log" was not owned by the running apache user.

**My apache user is bitnami:daemon...**

So for me the solution was:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon var/
```