# Trying to clone Magento 1.4.x site for development, how do I debug the white-screen-of-death?

Tags: php, magento-1.4

I've got full shell access, and phpMyAdmin, and I need to get this site working on a dev domain/new path (remote server, also hosts production site). Notably, I do *not* have server error logs.

It's worth pointinjg out that I have had luck at getting it to work on my local server, I understand about updating the unsecure & secure basurl's in the `core_config_data` table, but I can't seem to get the site working on our remote dev server, I just get white-screen. (To be sure, I've tried bumping up my error_reporting and error_level in index.php, changed nothing... that was about all I could glean from the webs, other than enabling it in the admin, which isn't an option currently).

Alright, thanks in advance, any advice appreciated.

Edit: Things I've done so far:

- error reporting is set at the top of index.php to `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`
- checked that logging was enabled in the database (it already was)
- I am able to die/echo output (using something like `die('arf');`) right up until the very last line of the index.php script, where it executes `Mage::run($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);` I haven't dove into that process, I'm sure it's just straight into the core & my problem is likely elsewhere.
- enabled `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);`
- no new files are being written to var/report

---

Edit #2:djot's answer below gave me a push in the right direction, and got me some output. 7800 lines of it actually, so here's the very last few lines before it ends, and i'll update this more later after i have some time to grok it a bit further:

```
File: /var/www/vhosts/somesite.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/shop/errors/processor.php[472]<br>
<script type="text/javascript">File: /var/www/vhosts/somesite.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/shop/errors/processor.php[475]<br>
window.location.href = 'http://dev.somesite.com/shop/errors/report.php?id=498275850056&skin=default';File: /var/www/vhosts/somesite.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/shop/errors/processor.php[476]<br>
</script>File: /var/www/vhosts/somesite.com/subdomains/dev/httpdocs/shop/errors/processor.php[477]<br>
```

Comment: what is the next lines in the file where it crashed (i.e. processor.php)? it seems like that's where the WSOD is happening

Comment: Yep indeed, this is exactly where I needed to look. That line (477) is inside of a ~20-line function called saveReport, and I'm getting a hunch now that isn't working right (since it isn't dumping reports as one would expect), and it's probably because of the permissions on my /var/report folder. And permissions is probably my bigger issue. I think I need to take this to the hosting provider. Thanks very much again, I'll post back if my hunch is right.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some steps you can take:

- Make sure that PHP error reporting is enabled. [PHP production server - turn on error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824282/php-production-server-turn-on-error-messages)
- Check Magento error logs in `var/logs`  [How to enable exception.log and system.log in Magento database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043291/how-to-enable-exception-log-and-system-log-in-magento-database)
- Try `var_dump("Something, Please!")` on the first line of index.php
- If you still see nothing, then the problem is probably with the PHP configuration / apache

Comment: Thanks, updated my question to address these. I think Apache/PHP is ok though, since our prod site is running on this same server.

Answer (score 2):

Debugging white screens of death is possible with prints or echos at special lines, breakpoints. Unfortunately, this is very annoying, if you have a lot of code. So, one solution is to "tick" every line, until php crashes.

```
declare(ticks=1);
register_tick_function('TickLine', TRUE);


function TickLine() {
  $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
  echo 'File: ' . $backtrace[0]['file'] . '[' . $backtrace[0]['line'] . ']<br>';
}
```

Comment: Man, this might've broken the ice-jam. I got like 7800 lines of output here, I'm going to update my post with this latest data. Thanks much!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the following line in your index.php file:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

Make it:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE']) || true) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
}
```

Also, clear out var/report (at least that is what it is in 1.6) then refresh and a new error should be there.

Let me know if you need more ideas.

Comment: You should really upgrade to 1.7, there are a LOT of security holes in 1.4, and honestly, its worth the work to upgrade.  It's a LOT faster and has a bunch more features.

Comment: Updated my question to address these, no luck on either front, still WSOD'ing. Thanks though!

Comment: yep indeed, this is what we're in the process of doing, cloning dev so we can start pushing upgrades. We've got an ancient Joomla install also, will be good to update them both, if this Magento issue here isn't the death of me, that is.

Comment: I run a software company if you need some more help, I have done a lot of work with Magento.  Upgrading any kind of Joomla install is a bear (trust me).  Depending, it may be easier to just manually transfer everything over.

Comment: I presume you have error_reporting(E_ALL) set and ini_set("display_errors",1) in index.php set, right?

Comment: Thanks yeah, Joomla doesn't scare me so much, I've spent more time mucking around in there, than with Magento. And yep I've got the error stuff cranked.

Comment: Do you have root access to this server, or is it shared? You can check your error_log file which is usually in /var/log/httpd/error_log or in a shared environment in various places

Comment: It's a managed server, no root, and the error logs are all locked down, I don't even have read permissions.

Comment: Interesting… Yeah, the way PHP works is, no matter what the error, it is logged in that file, so you may want to get in touch with your hosting company to either get access to those logs, or have them tell you where you can find them – access to your error logs is something one would expect from their web host

Comment: Agreed. It's a sorry state of affairs. Thanks for the advice though!