# Log files in Magento 1.9 installtion (XAMPP Windows 7)

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am struggling to find the log directory on my Magento 1.9 installation. Please note that I have used XAMPP and this in installed on Windows 7.

I have checked many forums and the following are the things I have already tried but with no change.

1. Updated System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings > Enabled = Yes
2. The var directory under C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\var did not have the directory 'log'. So I created this directory and change the permission settings to full access.
3. Disabled cache under System -> Cache Management
4. Also manually deleted browser cookies before testing each of the above.

I am quite new to Magento. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Aarthi

Comment: If u enable log setting from back-end then in var/log u will got system log files.

Comment: Hi Niraj, Can you please elaborate? Where are the system log file?

Comment: have a look at following links,http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/magento/203-troubleshooting-magento/enabling-system-and-exception-logging-in-magento    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12043291/how-to-enable-exception-log-and-system-log-in-magento-database

Comment: yes I had tried your solution (#1 in my list of trials). No luck. /var/log directory is empty. 
Also I am at a very early stage to think about saving logs in db. I just want to see the system.log and exception.log

Comment: have u refreshed frontend and backend both? because this files has benn create while we run script. so try to refresh frontend and backend.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps:

- Go to System > Configuration > Developer > Log Settings, and set:

Enabled = Yes

- Click on var/log folder and open properties of that folder.
- Click on Security tab and check that all users have full permission. (if not then grant full permission)
- Edit any controller's action, and add Mage::log('test'); and open that action's URL in browser.
- Then check /var/log folder.